# Laravel relationship many to many count related data by foreign key

Tags: laravel, relationship, eloquent-relationship, laravel-7

I have 3 models in my project:

**User** model code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function professions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Profession', 'user_professions');
    }
}
```

**Profession** model code

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Profession extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User', 'user_professions');
    }
}
```

**Migration:**

```
$table->id();
$table->string("name");
$table->timestamps();
```

**UserProfession** model code

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserProfession extends Model
{
    //
}
```

**Migration:**

```
$table->id();
$table->foreignId('user_id')
  ->constrained()
  ->onDelete('cascade');
$table->foreignId('profession_id')
  ->constrained()
  ->onDelete('cascade');
```

When I try this code where I search users by his name and get there professions name then count users in that professions.

**Code:**

```
$query = $request->get("query");
$users = User::where("name", "like", "%".$query."%");
$userIds = $users->get()->pluck("id")->toArray();

$professions = Profession::whereHas("users", function($q) use($userIds) {
    $q->whereIn('id', $userIds);
})->get()->toArray();
```

I get error with message:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous
>   (SQL: select * from professions where exists (select * from users
>   inner join user_professions on users.id = user_professions.user_id
>   where professions.id = user_professions.profession_id and id in (11,
>   43, 82)))

Where I have error in my code and how I can fix it?

Comment: `$q->whereIn('id', $userIds);` you need to ask yourself what id? users.id? Professions.id?

Comment: users id in `$userIds` in my case. I've logical mistake? @Avi

Comment: because laravel don't know which table's `id` do u want

Comment: How I can correct my query? @TsaiKoga

Comment: Make table name `profession_user` following Laravel's convention and it'll save you some headache. Check (also here very) [good practice](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three tables `users`,`user_professions` and `professions` that all have `id` column.

You need to specify which table's id that you want:

```php
$professions = Profession::whereHas("users", function($q) use($userIds) {
    $q->whereIn('users.id', $userIds); // specify the table name
})->get()->toArray();
```